# how do i jump to the next input for intellisense

Tags: intellij-idea, terraform, intellij-plugin

I'm using the terraform plugin specifically but this is a more general intellij hotkey question.

I start typing a supported element and autocomplete pops up:

[image]

Hit tab and it sets up the method and puts the cursor in the first input and I can start typing and it gives me possible inputs:

[image]

But when i hit tab or enter it just completes it and leaves the cursor where it is:
[image]

Is there a hotkey to complete one of those options and then also jump to the next input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ticket for this feature, but its not implemented yet, please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7063

Comment: I use the vim plugin and "E" usually moves me to the right place in this scenario so I can get by with that for now- doesn't autocomplete though.